# How can I see all packages that depend on a certain package with PIP?

Tags: python, package, pip

I would like to see a list of packages that depend on a certain package with PIP. That is, given `django`, I would like to see `django-cms`, `django-filer`, because I have these packages installed and they all have `django` as dependency.

Comment: PIP installed: `pip 1.4.1`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Update (2021):

Since `pip` [version 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64152561/1107807) you can do:

```
pkg=httplib2
pip show $pkg | grep ^Required-by
```

or for bash

```
pkg=httplib2
grep ^Required-by <(pip show $pkg)
```

so you could create an alias like:

```
alias pyreq='pip show $pkg | grep ^Required-by'
```

and querying by:

```
pkg=httplib2 pyreq
```

which should give (for ubuntu):

```
Required-by: lazr.restfulclient, launchpadlib
```

---

Original:

Quite straightforward:

```
pip show <insert_package_name_here>| grep ^Requires
```

Or the other way around: (sorry i got it wrong!)

```
for NAME in $(pip freeze | cut -d= -f1); do REQ=$(pip show $NAME| grep Requires); if [[ "$REQ" =~ "$REQUIRES" ]]; then echo $REQ;echo "Package: $NAME"; echo "---" ; fi;  done
```

before that set your search-string with:

```
REQUIRES=django
```

essentially you have to go through the whole list and query for every single one. That may take some time.

---

*Edit:
Also it does only work on installed packages, I don't see pip providing dependencies on not installed packages.*

Comment: You got it wrong. I would like to see what _required_ the given package, not what _requires_ the given package.

Comment: @DonQuestion But this only shows it for the currently installed packages right? Is there anyway to search through the whole PyPi list?

Comment: This does not work, but returns an error: 

Usage:   
  pip show [options] <package> ...

no such option: ------------------

Comment: leaving this for my sad self while skipping warning to run this on a deprecated python version `for NAME in $(python -W ignore -m pip freeze | cut -d= -f1); do REQ=$(python -W ignore -m pip show $NAME| grep Requires); if [[ "$REQ" =~ "$REQUIRES" ]]; then echo $REQ;echo "Package: $NAME"; echo "---" ; fi;  done`

Answer (score 29):

I know there's already an accepted answer here, but really, it seems to me that what you want is to use [pipdeptree](https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree):

```
pip install pipdeptree
pipdeptree --help

pipdeptree -r -p django
```

Comment: Should be accepted answer!

Reason: 
1. works on the python ecosystem, more comfortable for a python developer than the answer by @Don_Question.
2. Very simplistic commands
3. Mentions CLI Tool specifically designed to solve OP's question

Comment: You have a point here! But pipdeptree is much younger then the question. And if you need a one shot solution you really don't want to install a package, when you can do it in "one" line of shellscript! ;-)

Comment: Just wanted to note explicitly that this (good) answer shares a limitation with accepted answer: it won't tell you about packages that aren't installed. (I came here looking for that additional functionality to troubleshoot a package that won't install on my M1 Mac.)

Comment: @PaulBissex were you able find any workaround for your case. Facing similar issue

Answer (score 7):

Since version 10, `pip show` also includes a "Required-by" entry. So just

```
pip show <package_name>
```

is enough nowadays. Or possibly

```
pip show <package_name> | grep ^Required-by
```

if you want to get just that single line for a script or whatever.

Answer (score 5):

This one, for pip older than 1.3.1 will list all packages and it's dependencies, you can parse its output with any scripting language, for `Requires ... django` inclusions:

```
pip freeze | cut -f 1 -d'=' |  xargs -L1 pip show
```

For example, following snippet:

```
import os
import re

package = 'numpy'
regex = re.compile('.*{}($|,).*'.format(package))

def chunks(l, n): return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

cmd = "pip freeze | cut -f 1 -d'=' |  xargs -L1 pip show"
packages = os.popen(cmd).read()
pkg_infos = chunks(packages.splitlines(), 5)
print '\n'.join(x[1][6:] for x in filter(lambda x: regex.match(x[-1]), pkg_infos))
```

outputs `pandas` on my system.

Comment: I was looking for something more straight-forward, something that requires only some shell commands.

Comment: @linkyndy take a look at my answer! :-)

Answer (score 2):

One liner based on requirements.txt. In this example I'm looking for `funcsigs` reverse dependency, and found mock. Just change `funcsigs` by something else.

```
cat requirements.txt | grep -v git | sed 's/==.*//' | xargs -I % echo 'pip show % 2>/dev/null | grep Requires | grep -q funcsigs && echo %' | sh
```